# KDB: Connection Error Between ODBC and SQL Server; Crashes Midway Through Running Query

Tags: sql, odbc, bigdata, kdb

I am using `odbc.eval` on KDB to run a SQL stored procedure that generates over tens of millions of rows of data. We have 2 different RDBs (SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2016) set up with the same data, allocated memory, etc. The KDB code works against one of them, but doesn't work against the other. For the newer server, KDB crashes midway through the query. The stored procedure seems to work on SQL Management Studio 2016 just fine, though it does take a long time to fully execute - around an hour or so. Could this be a time-out error? Any suggestions for running a SQL query with this large amount of data on KDB without running into memory or timeout issues?

Comment: Are there any errors thrown then your kdb server crashes?
Also are you using the same ODBC driver with both SQL servers?

Comment: Yes it returns the error "-w abort".

Comment: This means you have hit your workspace limit set on the command line with the -w parameter. You can check your memory limits using .Q.w[]. This will return a dictionary.
The wmax value will tell you your limit in bytes, if you exceed this it will throw -w abort. You can remove this limit by increasing -w on the command line or removing it completely. You memory will then be constrained by your os.

Comment: Thanks @Gilmer. How do you remove -w on the command line though?

Comment: A kdb process will be started using this syntax;
    q -w 100000
If you can find this in your config and change it to 0 (unlimited) or just increase the value that should work. It sounds like you are pulling a lot of data into memory though so you should be careful not to blow up your machine.